# How can I reorder this binary file

Tags: c++, file, binary, byte, endianness

[image]

I have this two binary file which are the outputs of a java code and a C++ code in the same machine.
The problem is that the bytes order seems to be different (maybe little endian vs big endian?).
So the question is: why are this different on the same machine? And how can I convert/view the file in the same byte order to compare them?

The file on the left is achieved using:

```
  std::ofstream file("binary.bin", std::ios::binary);

  for (const auto& row : vector) {
      file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(row.data()), row.size() * sizeof(float));
  }

  file.close();
```

And in Java (right):

```
File file = new File(path, "/" + "binary2.bin");
 try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
            fos.write(byteArray);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show a [mre] of the code that produced these files or a specification of their format

Comment: @AlanBirtles I simply wrote on two `.bin` file from Java code and from C++ code. Do I need to post also the code?

Comment: ***And how can I convert/view the file in the same byte order to compare them?*** Unless you know the format you can't just convert because the binary file could have different sized data (1 byte, 2 byte, 4 byte, 8 byte ...) or possible padding.

Comment: Showing a solution in the answer below which is just reversing 4 byte blocks. Whatever this means for the real source data . . .

Comment: I edit my answer with the code I use to produce the .bin file in C++

Comment: Still not a [mre], what is `byteArray`? How is it populated?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not that many information are given. It looks like blocks of 4 bytes are reversed.

This may be implementation dependent. C++ stores in one way, and Java in the other way. But since we cannot see the programs doing the writing, we can just guess. We also cannot see the structure of the file (1 byte data or 2 byte data or 4 byte data or 8 byte data blocks or structures with padding or whatever)

But, at least we can reorder 4 byte blocks of binary data.

That is not complicated. We open the file at hand, read all data in a `std::vector` and then close the file.

Then we reopen the file again for writing, which will overwrite all content that was previously in it. The file will be empty.

We iterate over the source data in the `std::vector` and reverse 4-byte blocks with the `std::reverse` function from the algorithm library.

Finally, we write back all data to the file.

I drafted some demo functions to create a test file and show the contens.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <filesystem>
#include <algorithm>

const std::string testFileName{ "test.bin" };

// Simple program to write test data to a file
void writeTestFile() {
    // Open file for writing and check, if it is open
    if (std::ofstream ofs(testFileName,std::ios::binary); ofs) {
        // Write 128 4-byte blocks
        for (int i{}; i < 128; ++i)
            for (int k{ 3 }; k >= 0; --k)
                ofs << static_cast<unsigned char>(i * 4 + k);
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n*** Error. Could not open file '" << testFileName << "' for writing\n\n";
}
// Show binary file content on screen in hex
void showBinaryFile() {
    // Open file and check, if it could be opened
    if (std::ifstream ifs(testFileName, std::ios::binary); ifs) {
        std::cout << "\n\n---------------------------------------------------------------\n";
        unsigned int counterForLineBreak{};

        // Read all data from file in a loop and display it
        for (unsigned char c = ifs.get(); ifs; c = ifs.get()) {
            std::cout << std::right << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << static_cast<unsigned int>(c) << ' ';
            if (++counterForLineBreak % 16 == 0) std::cout << '\n';
        }
    } 
    else std::cerr << "\n*** Error. Could not open file '" << testFileName << "' for reading\n\n";
}
// Simply reverse 4 byte blocks of a binary file
// File size must be multiple of 4
void flip() {
    // Open file for reading and check, if it could be opened
    if (std::ifstream ifs(testFileName, std::ios::binary); ifs) {

        // Read complete file into a std::vector
        std::size_t size{ std::filesystem::file_size(testFileName) };
        std::vector<unsigned char> content(size);
        ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(content.data()), size);
        // Close the file that we just read
        ifs.close();

        // Open file again. Now for writing. Check, if it could be opened
        if (std::ofstream ofs(testFileName, std::ios::binary); ofs) {

            // Reverse 4 byte blocks in std::vector
            for (std::size_t i{}; i < size; i += 4)
                std::reverse(content.data() + i, content.data() + std::min(i + 4, size));

            // Write data back to file
            ofs.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(content.data()), size);
        }
        else std::cerr << "\n*** Error. Could not open file '" << testFileName << "' for writing\n\n";
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n*** Error. Could not open file '" << testFileName << "' for reading\n\n";

}
// Test program
int main() {
    writeTestFile();
    showBinaryFile();
    flip();
    showBinaryFile();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But is there a way to achieve this BEFORE writing the file? Can I set the byte order in Java or C++, so I don't have to reorder in a second step? Thanks. I updated the question